# Jquery: fadeOut happens immediately after fadeIn

Tags: jquery

I've got two elements (one is button) and would like to make that when I press button another element would fade in and stay. And only when I press button again, it would fade out. Now what I've got is that it does fade out automatically before I press the button again. What kind of "stop" do I need to use? Thanks.

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#first").click(function() { 
    $("#box").fadeIn("slow");
  });

  $("#first").click(function() { 
    $("#box").fadeOut("slow"); 
  });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#first").click(function() { 
    $("#box").fadeToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

click adds function to stack of functions that are happening when event occurs. in your code you are doing both things at once when user clicks the element.

Comment: Don't forget to select the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can also specify the button state... This will work for all kinds of functions, even those that don't have the *toggle* version of them (like `fadeToggle`). Like this:

```
var buttonFaded = false;
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#first").click(function() { 
        if (buttonFaded) {
            $("#box").fadeIn("slow");
            buttonFaded = true; // even better to put this inside the fadeIn callback
        else {
            $("#box").fadeOut("slow");
            buttonFaded = false;
        }
    });
});
```

EDIT

If you just need the most basic usage, @fsw's example will work perfectly. However, if you need any customizations/more complex usages, you'd have to do something like this.

p.s. greetings to the downvoter - hopefully you'll understand some day

Comment: +1 indeed you have more control this way. you can also use something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524541/jquery-fadetoggle-different-actions-if-element-is-visible-or-not to check what fadeToggle did.

Comment: @fsw Yeah, it all depends on what you need. I'm used to doing it this way because there are usually more things related to the state of the button than just the fade effect, even things not related to the button at all... and in such cases the less jQuery you use, the better (such as checking the visible attribute every time you need something) :)

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $("#first").on('click', (function() {
    //check #box visibility state
    if($('#box').is(':visible')){
        $('#box').fadeOut('slow');
    }
    else{
        $('#box').fadeIn("slow");
    }
});
```